# Android: Path parameters in HTTP get method by retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have this api link:

```
http://www.xxxx.com/?apikey=mykey&i=tt036543
```

Now by retrofit I am trying to call this api with GET method so I can create this interface:

```
@GET("/?apikey=mykey&i={movie_id}")
Call<MovieDetailEntity> getSearchedMovie(@Path("movie_id") String id);
```

But I  got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "apikey=mykey&i={movie_id}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.
    for method BatmanService.getSearchedMovie
```

If I use this Query :

```
@GET("/?apikey=mykey&i=")
Call<MovieDetailEntity> getSearchedMovie(@Query("movie_id") String id);
```

Then the link changes to :

```
http://www.xxxx.com/?apikey=mykey&i=&movie_id=tt036543
```

How can I call this api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember well once you use @query you should not set the variable at the url. It will use the string inside the @query annotation as the variable name.

This should work:

```
@GET("/?apikey=mykey")
Call<MovieDetailEntity> getSearchedMovie(@Query("i") String id);
```

And also this, if you want to pass your api key as well:

```
@GET("/")
Call<MovieDetailEntity> getSearchedMovie(@Query("apikey") String mykey,
                                         @Query("i") String id);
```

The ? and & are automatically added for you.